# Why does map/filter ... not work with an Array of Nothing?

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, higher-order-functions

Isn't Nothing a subtype of all types?

```
scala> val array = new Array(5)
array: Array[Nothing] = Array(null, null, null, null, null)

scala> array.map(_ => 42)
<console>:9: error: value map is not a member of Array[Nothing]
       array.map(_ => 42)
             ^

scala> array.filter(_ != 42)
<console>:9: error: value filter is not a member of Array[Nothing]
       array.filter(_ != 42)
             ^
```

It's weird that this doesn't work.

Is this specified, a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you see weird behavior involving Nothing, it's because the type inference algorithm thinks that it inserted Nothing itself, since it is introduced during type inference: if nothing is known about a type variable then it is bounded by Any and Nothing.  It has long been on my list of things to do to see if I can introduce a new internal-only bottom type for that purpose so user-level Nothing and inference-level Nothing are not intermingled, but it's a pretty ambitious task.  Still, I might now be hardcore enough to try it.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect Scala shouldn't let you do that kind of `Array[Nothing]` instantiation. There are by definition no instances of nothing around, yet your array looks like it's filled with `Nothing`s that are null, but null is not a valid value for `Nothing`. This for instance fails with the error `type mismatch; found : Null(null) required: Nothing`

```
val n: Nothing = null
```

So I'd expect to run into trouble each time you can actually fool the system to believe you are finally getting hold of a much sought for instance of `Nothing`…

Here's another weird case. Run this:

```
object Main {

  class Parametrized[T] { var value: T = _ }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p = new Parametrized // typed as Parametrized[Nothing]
    val n = p.value  // n is now actually an instance of Nothing... isn't it?
    println(p.value) // prints null, but null is not an instance of Nothing
    println(n)       // throws NullPointerException...
  }

}
```

Comment: The `null` isn't really a `null`, it is more like a `throw new NullPointerException`. The `toString` is a bit misleading.

Comment: @soc I realize that now: the compiler actually “unboxes” `null` as a `Nothing` by throwing. Funny it doesn't do it on the `println(p.value)` here above.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the Scala Array type is invariant. So `Nothing` being a subtype of everything may not be relevant.

Also `map` and `filter` are not defined on `Array`. Implicit conversions in `Predef` are used to provide such methods for arrays.

So the compiler is unable to find an implicit conversion from `Array[Nothing]` to something that has the `map` or `filter` defined. Using the REPL, I can actually see that such an implicit conversion should be available:

```
scala> val conv = implicitly[Array[Nothing] <%< collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Nothing]]

conv: <%<[Array[Nothing],scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Nothing]] = <function1>

scala> conv(new Array[Nothing](5)).filter(_ => true)
res8: Array[Nothing] = Array(null, null, null, null, null)
```

So the question becomes why the compiler does not consider the [`genericArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html#genericArrayOps%5BT%5D%28Array%5BT%5D%29%3aArrayOps%5BT%5D) conversion.

Comment: Nice trick to test in the REPL whether an implicit conversion is available!