# Testing an array for emptiness in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The question isn't about *how* to test an array for emptiness (`arr.length == 0` does this fine).  Rather my question is, why does

```
scala> Array().isEmpty
res1: Boolean = true
```

work and

```
scala> val x = Array[String]()
x: Array[String] = Array()
scala> x.isEmpty
res2: Boolean = true
```

work, but

```
scala> val y = Array()
y: Array[Nothing] = Array()

scala> y.isEmpty
<console>:13: error: value isEmpty is not a member of Array[Nothing]
       y.isEmpty
         ^
```

does not?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843001/why-does-map-filter-not-work-with-an-array-of-nothing

Comment: Funny, `Array().isEmpty` works :)

Comment: Seems as though `Array().isEmpty` works because `Array()` hasn't yet been inferred as empty, so it picks up `Predef.refArrayOps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MichaelZajac points out, `Nothing` is a subtype of everything (its counterpart `Any` is a supertype of everything). In particular it's also a subtype of `AnyRef`. In fact there's an even more general `genericArrayOps` which has no type bound at all (e.g. `Array[Any]().isEmpty` works)! The implicit conversion allowing you to use `isEmpty` *should* kick in, but of course it doesn't, even though explicitly calling the conversion is fine.

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843001/why-does-map-filter-not-work-with-an-array-of-nothing) @slouc gives is the answer, namely that the Scala compiler treats `Nothing` in a special way when doing implicit resolution because `Nothing` is the default lower bound for a type when doing type inference.

Now why exactly would it ever be desirable for `Nothing` not to be considered in implicit resolution? Well the tricky thing about `Nothing` again is that it's a subtype of everything. This means that if at any point Scala infers a type to be `Nothing`, every single implicit conversion would immediately become valid. This could hide a type error (you should never have an instance of `Nothing`, but when that `Nothing` becomes an `Int`... well who's to say?). (Note I would love for someone who actually hacks on the compiler to jump in and confirm/deny/elaborate on this)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: probably this answer is not correct. But I'm keepeing it here to show how did I try to investigate this issue. To me it looks like a bug in the compiler.**

The answer is implicit conversion that exists for `Array[T <: AnyRef]`
String is `AnyRef`, `Nothing` is not `AnyRef`.

**How could you discover this yourself?**

In IntelliJ you can see a grey underline under the `isEmpty`
[image]

This means that the method `isEmpty` is not a method of Array, but an implicit (a method on a class that has implicit conversion from Array).

Now, to discover the implicit conversion, just click `ctrl+q`
[image]

So when you follow it, you get to this line in the source code -

```
  implicit def refArrayOps[T <: AnyRef](xs: Array[T]): ArrayOps[T]    = new ArrayOps.ofRef[T](xs)
```

That explains that the implicit conversion is on an Array[T] when T extends AnyRef

***So back to our case -*** 
`String <: AnyRef`, but this doesn't hold for `Nothing`

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanks so much for the explanation!  I'm not the biggest fan of IntelliJ, but that's a cool feature.

Comment: This reasoning here isn't true. `Nothing` _is absolutely_ a sub-type of `AnyRef`. Try: `refArrayOps[Nothing](Array()).isEmpty` -- it works just fine. The reason why the implicit doesn't kick-in for `y.isEmpty` is far more dubious than that.

Comment: @MichaelZajac What do you mean by "far more dubious"?